# Two wheeler front suspension

Tags: suspension, scooter

My two wheeler's front suspension seems to be disloyal it does not absorb the pot holes it is supposed to instead it pass it on to my hands which ends up vibrating my entire body.What is the diagnosis process of it.How can I go ahead with repairing this, are there any parts which I can repair/replace like bearing ,bush or oil.etc.My Scooter is **Honda Activa** and is around 2 years old and clocked around 7000 kms.

Comment: What kind of scooter do you own. We can possibly get you a more detailed answer with specific information.

Comment: Is this the Honda Active you have asked other questions about? Honestly, I am not sure you have a problem. Scooters do not designed to have the ability to absorb all of the shock like an automobile. The smaller and lighter the vehicle, the more difficult to absorb those road conditions. With any bike, there is going to be some transfer to the rider no matter what you do. Avoiding the potholes is probably the best solution.

Comment: @CharlieRB yes this is the same Honda Activa I had asked the question about.I have ridden other Activa also they seem to be doing the work of absorbing the shocks wonderfully but mine is a little on harder side.So I was wondering if this could be solved by some repairing stuff

Comment: It is important for your question to include those details so we can understand what you are working with. There is no way for us to know what you have already experienced. It would be helpful to also know how old the scooter is and how many miles/Km are on it. Please add those details to the question above using the [edit] feature.

Comment: @CharlieRB.I just edited my question to include some more details

Answer (score 1):

Three things :

1) check tyre pressures,

2) check the shock absorber - replace if necessary,

3) avoid potholes - especially the larger ones as they can cause damage or, more seriously, an accident.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be breakdown in the damping mechanism of the suspension system. Without the effect of the damper you are experiencing only the spring. Depending on the suspension type the damper may need to be replaced or re-gassed or the oil refreshed and set to the correct level. To confirm the condition of the damper you can compress the suspension with the bike stationary and observe the speed at which the bike rebounds - if the bike rebounds very quickly then the damping is not functioning.